# How to test if the relationship between a predictor and an outcome variable varies as a function of a within-subjects categorical variable?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, anova, repeated-measures

I am designing a study that has the objective of assessing if working memory varies throughout the day (morning vs. afternoon). I will measure 5 components of working memory with 5 cognitive tasks. The same group of participants will complete these tasks in a morning session and an afternoon session.

Our participants will be university students who completed a math subject whose classes were exclusively taught in the morning and a second math subject whose classes were exclusively taught in the afternoon. We also want to assess if the participants had better grades in math subjects whose schedules are aligned with the peak of working memory than in math subjects whose schedules are not aligned with this peak.

My design is completely within-subjects: the same participants will complete 5 working memory tasks (we will measure the accuracy in each of these tasks on a scale ranging from 0 to 100). These participants must have completed a math subject whose classes were exclusively taught in the morning and a second math subject whose classes were exclusively taught in the afternoon (these classes are measured on a scale ranging from 0 to 20).

To recap, I am interested in testing the following questions:

1 – Does working memory performance vary as a function of time of day (morning vs. afternoon) – Is working memory performance better in the afternoon or in the morning?

2 – Do academic achievement in math grades vary as a function of time of day (morning vs. afternoon) – are the grades of math subjects whose classes were exclusively taught in the afternoon better than the grades of math subjects whose classes were exclusively taught in the morning, or vice versa?

3 – Does working memory performance predict academic achievement in math subjects?

4 – And this is the main question – Does the relationship between working memory performance and academic achievement in math subjects vary as a function of time? In other words, do the variations in working memory performance caused by the time of day explain a portion of the variations in math grades caused by time of day?

I leave an image with the model I intend to build attached to this message ("Manhã" means morning and "Tarde" means afternoon in Portuguese). I only included a single predictor in this mock-up of the model to simplify its interpretation. My actual model will include 5 predictors (accuracy in 5 working memory tasks that will represent indirect measures of 5 different components of working memory).

Can anyone help me identify the statistical analysis technique more suitable to build this model and to test the questions I previously mentioned? I am a Psychology student so I am not exactly an expert in statistics. I already have explored several techniques (repeated-measures MANOVA, hierarchical mixed linear models, repeated-measures moderation) but I found that all of them had some drawbacks. But again, I am not a statistics expert, so I may have misunderstood some things when I explored these options.

Thank you so much for your help.

Fábio.

[image]

Comment: You will need to have some who first attempt the task as a morning task (subsequently afternoon) and some who attempt it first as an afternoon task (later as a morning task), to account for the learning  effect